# Divide UI in rows shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm having a problem with my UI in shiny. I need the dashboardBody to be divided by two rows.

The first row is divided by 2 columns. One with one plot and the other with 2 plots, each one in a row.

The second row is divided by 3 columns, each one with a infoBox.

This is my code:

```
dashboardPage(skin = 'green',
  dashboardHeader(title = 'Zanity - Análise de Dados e Consultoria', titleWidth = 400),
  dashboardSidebar(width = 400),
  dashboardBody(
    box(title = 'Weekly revenue', plotlyOutput('plot_revenue')),
    box(title = 'Loading %', plotlyOutput('plot_porc_loading')),
    box(title = 'Manufacture', plotly('plot_manu')),
    fluidRow(
      infoBox('Ex. Load', 200, icon = icon('weight')),
      infoBox('Loading %', '0.97%', icon = icon('percent')),
      infoBox('Revenue', 'R$ 60.000,00', icon = icon('dollar-sign'))
    )
  )
)
```

This is how I want it to look:

[ideal layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuRHF.png)

Answer (score 2):

See below: the trick is first dividing everything into `fluidRow()` and then diving each row in `column()` and understanding each column has a `width = 12` even if the column in the row isn't.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = 'green',
  dashboardHeader(title = 'Zanity - Análise de Dados e Consultoria', titleWidth = 400),
  dashboardSidebar(width = 400),
  dashboardBody(
    #First Row:
    fluidRow(
      column(6,
             box(title = 'Weekly revenue', width = 12)
             ),
      column(6,
             box(title = 'Loading %', width = 12),
             box(title = 'Manufacture', width = 12)
             )
    ),
    #Second Row:
    fluidRow(
      infoBox('Ex. Load', 200, icon = icon('weight')),
      infoBox('Loading %', '0.97%', icon = icon('percent')),
      infoBox('Revenue', 'R$ 60.000,00', icon = icon('dollar-sign'))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It did work, but I'm still having problems with the row sizes.

In each box I'm ploting a graph. When I render the shiny app, all the boxes are the same heigth, then the display is not the same as the picture I posted.

I've tried to adjust the height, but i got the same result.

Comment: You need to use CSS and adjust the box height, not the plot. If you can provide a simple reproducible example (both UI and server), I can try to help

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help. However, I have zero knowledge in CSS. I'll study a little and then I'll ask for your help. Otherwise you might end up doing all this work and I won't be able to use it.

Thanks again, really!